# Unity 2d : gameobject set active wont work for parent and all children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made two scripts for a game 2d unity. The one sets a bool true into the other and here is the code of the other:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float weapons;
    public float money;
    public bool tutorial = true;
    public bool tutorialcoins = false;
    public bool tutorialsword = false;
    public bool tutorialenemies = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (tutorial)
        {

    if (!tutorialcoins)
        {
            GameObject.Find("Coins").SetActive(false);
        }
        }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (tutorialcoins)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Coins").SetActive(true);
    }

 }
```

So I used that code and the Object named Coins and it has a lot of children. When I set tutorialcoins to true the children nor the Coins get activated and nothing happens! Please do you know anything I possibly have done wrong

Comment: cant find game object cause disabled but how can i enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public Transform coin;
     void Start()
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < coin.childCount; j++)
         {
             coin.GetChild(j).gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }
     }

void Update()
{
    if (tutorialcoins)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < coin.childCount; j++)
             {
                 coin.GetChild(j).gameObject.SetActive(false);
             }
    }

 }
```

After adding this code. Go to the object that you attached this script to. on the script component you will see `Coin`. drag your Coins obj from hierarchy to this and run.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GameManagerScript.Update () (at Assets/GameManagerScript.cs:43) (The line of for (int j = 0; j < coin.childCount; j++))

Comment: try this code that i update and pass the coin obj from inspector.

Comment: what do you mean by pass the coin obj from the inspector.

Comment: I created a public var pass your coin obj to it.

Comment: 1st its a parent and it has many children in it I should put the parent in it? 2nd I put the parent and again it didn't work